# SQL db vs. Fusion Tables performance in Google Maps

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm developing an application that stores geolocation data in a SQL table to generate a map of all entered points/addresses by users. I would like this to scale to a large amount of points, possibly 50,000+ and still have great performance. Looking over the google maps API articles, however, they say performance can be greatly improved using fusion tables instead.

Does anyone have experience with this? Would performance suffer if I have thousands of markers loaded on a map from a SQL table? Does KML or any other strategy seem a better fit?

Once I'm zoomed out enough I could use MarkerClusters, but I'm not sure if that affects performance either since I'm still loading all the geocodes to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare both technologies.

When you load thousands of markers from a sql-database, you have to create each single marker, what of course will have bad performance, because you'll need to send the data for thousands of markers to the client and create the markers on client-side.

When you use fusion-tables, you don't load markers, you load tiles. It doesn't matter how many markers are visible on the tiles, the performance will always be the same.

KML is not an option, because the amount of features is limited(currently to 1000)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was wondering. This may seem like a silly question, but will that hold true if I use my own custom marker icons?

Comment: Yes, it will still be the same. A comparable approach would be when you also create tiles on serverside and use them as overlay. But I don't think that your server can do it faster than google.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps the only advantage is the fact that your data records may be kept private if you use some SQL table instead of Fusion Tables - but only if this is a concern in your project.

Daniel

Comment: Yes that is a concern of mine, actually. I'm asking users for their address/intersection to map points, but preferably I only want their geolocation data stored in the table, so I'm trying to work out a way to do that.

Comment: Does this helps: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3 ? I'm working in a project similar to it. Let me know if I may help somehow (and please vote up - I really need that!)